How to Read both Chinese and Vietnamese txt file?
I have to read txt file which include Chinese and Vietnamese word by C#
I used StreamReader to do this, my code
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default);
 
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename);

When I use
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.Default);

I can read Chinese but can not read Vietnamese.
When I use
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename);

I can read Vietnamese but can not read Chinese
How to Read both Chinese and Vietnamese txt file in C#?

It all depends on the encoding of the file. Put it to the same encoding (preferably one of the Unicode formats), read it with that encoding, done. If you can’t control the encoding of the files then you have to figure it out while reading somehow.

This 21 year old blog post still is invaluable today.

Here's how you can find out. Create a WinForms app. Drop a multiline textbox on it (using a unicode-capable font). Also drop a FileOpenDialog. Then drop a bottin to fire up the FileOpen dlg and a series of radio buttons that correspond to each of the static Encoding properties of the Encoding class. Pick one as a default. When you open a file, use the default encoding to read the file and set the Text property of the text box. If you click one of the radio bans, re-read the file with the new encoding and show it. If one works, that's the encoding you need
